# Continue executing long-running code after page output in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching, background-process

I have a backend data management console written with CakePHP that allows a user to manage some hierarchical data.  Every time a user makes a change to the data I want to regenerate a data file (JSON in this case) that's used on the site's frontend.

The rebuild can take some time and I'd like the backend UI to be a bit more responsive.  My idea is to have the JSON rebuild take place after the new page (the "your changes have been saved" page) is rendered to the user.  I've got some code within the `afterFilter()` call back in my `app_controller.php`, but the page doesn't actually render in the browser until the JSON rebuild completes.

I've found code examples for plain-vanilla PHP that does things like send a `Connection: Close` HTTP header and/or uses output buffer flushing to tell the browser that the server's done while processing continues, but these techniques don't (as far as I can tell) work with CakePHP's structure and its own output buffering.

What I would like is a technique that would allow me to completely render a view for the user and then, once the user has their page loaded, continue executing the JSON rebuild in the background.

I realize there may be situation/setup specific concerns that could affect things, so please let me know if you've got questions about my particular application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rather suggest you delegate this task entirely to a background daemon/cron job/queue worker, than piggybacking on a "UI thread".

Comment: If that were an option I would definitely do it.  Unfortunately it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those cakephp queue plugins are invented for this exact purpose:
https://github.com/MSeven/cakephp_queue

they decouple the frontend from the backend services like those file generations.

Comment: This looks promising. Are there plans to make them 2.0 compatible? If nothing has started I may look into forking. ;)

Comment: well, I tried and almost completed it :) seems to work for me: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp_queue

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion. This is how I ran long running processes from the UI for scrubbing files. First create a SHELL for doing the processing. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#Shell

This will provide the code that will run the background process you are looking to run.

Then, setup the method in the UI side to call the shell. Grab the PID and save it to the database (so you can tell when it finished).

```
$PID = shell_exec("/path/to/cake/console/cake SHELLNAME SHELLMETHOD");
$this->Jobs->query("UPDATE `jobs` SET `pid` = $pid WHERE `id` = $job_id");
```

Then you can always check to see if the process is running by checking the `/proc/$PID`.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I took the much more labor-intensive way of writing a basic RESTful interface and calling it via AJAX. I spent a bunch of time trying to get asynchrous cURL to work, before I went down that path. I think your suggestion is a good technique to be aware of. Thanks.